# I can't figure out how to install this program in Debian

Tags: debian

I'm trying to install this program from GitHub called [Backbox-Anonymous](https://github.com/raffaele-forte/backbox-anonymous).

However I couldn't find any installation guide among the documentation. Can someone explain to me how to install it please?

Answer (score 7):

[Murphy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/157411/murphy)’s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390709/86440) is pretty much correct, but I would suggest installing the binary in `/usr/local/sbin` instead since it’s not packaged. (Outside of `/usr/local`, `/usr` should ideally contain only packaged software.)

If you have a shell open in the `blackbox-anonymous` directory, the installation process boils down to

```
sudo cp etc/default/blackbox-anonymous /etc/default/
sudo install usr/sbin/anonymous /usr/local/sbin
```

The latter will ensure that the script is executable.

Answer (score 2):

You just copy the files to the directories `/usr/sbin` and `/etc/default`, as they are placed in the project. Make sure to set executable permissions for `/usr/sbin/anonymous`.